# Swing: detect mouse move on generalpath

Tags: java, swing, spline

I'm drawing some splines using GeneralPath as follow:

```
GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
path.moveTo(x0, y0);
path.curveTo(x0 + 100, y0, x1 - 100, y1, x1, y1);
((Graphics2D) g).draw(path);
```

Basically, this draws a spline that looks like a cable, or wire, between the point (x0;y0) and the point (x1;y1).

```
p0 --
     \
      \
       `-- p1
```

The drawing is okay, but now I would like to detect when the mouse moves hover this spline. The problem is that the `contains(Point)` method does not seems to do what I want. It returns `true` if the `Point` is inside the area between the spline and a direct line between (x0;y0) and (x1;y1).

In the example above, it will return true for the whole "stars" area:

```
p0 -----------
     *********\
         ******\
             ***\
                *\* 
                  \******* 
                   `------------- p1
```

But only want to detect when the point is exactly located on the spline.

Is there any way to achieve what I want ?

Any ideas greatly appreciated !

EDIT:
I found the explanation of my problem in the documentation, but this does not help me to find a solution:

> The contains and intersects methods
>   consider the interior of a Shape to be
>   the area it encloses as if it were
>   filled. This means that these methods
>   consider unclosed shapes to be
>   implicitly closed for the purpose of
>   determining if a shape contains or
>   intersects a rectangle or if a shape
>   contains a point.

Comment: Is it possible to estimate the line between the points by calculating the line equation (y = ax + b, where a,b are constants)? You can use that to estimate if the (x,y) of the mouse are over the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a curveTo back to the starting point. But it's going to be really, really hard for the user to get *exactly* over your curve!

Comment: I found a solution. I created a 'selection path' that represents the area between my spline and my spline translated by 6 pixels in X (+ the same for Y). Thanks for your answer!